# How to put an Html Page in a spring-boot application using Gradle

Tags: html, gradle, spring-boot

I followed this guide to create a REST Web Service:
https://spring.io/guides/gs/rest-service/

Everything is working fine, I can visit http://localhost:8080/greeting to see the helloworld greeting.  But what I want to do is add an html page to the website, that makes an AJAX call to the web service.  I was just wondering where I place this html file and what url I would have to visit to see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to https://spring.io/blog/2013/12/19/serving-static-web-content-with-spring-boot you just have to put your file in `/META-INF/resources/`, `/resources/`, `/static/` or `/public/` to get it served automatically. So just putting it into `src/main/resources/static/foo.html` should probably be enough to be able to access it as `http://localhost:8080/foo.html`.